# does python have conversion operators?

Tags: python, operators

I don't think so, but I thought I'd ask just in case.  For example, for use in a class that encapsulates an int:

```
i = IntContainer(3)
i + 5
```

And I'm not just interested in this int example, I was looking for something clean and general, not overriding every int and string method.

Thanks, sunqiang.  That's just what I wanted.  I didn't realize you could subclass these immutable types (coming from C++).

```
class IntContainer(int):
    def __init__(self,i):
        #do stuff here
        self.f = 4

    def MultiplyBy4(self):
        #some member function
        self *= self.f
        return self

print 3+IntContainer(3).MultiplyBy4()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sometimes maybe just subclass from int directly is enough. then `__add__` and `__radd__` need not costuming.

```
class IntContainer(int):
    pass
i = IntContainer(3)
print i + 5 # 8 
print 4 + i # 7

class StrContainer(str):
    pass
s = StrContainer(3)
print s + '5' # 35
print '4' + s # 43
```

Answer (score 13):

This should do what you need:

```
class IntContainer(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def __add__(self, other):
        # do some type checking on other
        return self.x + other

    def __radd__(self, other):
        # do some type checking on other
        return self.x + other
```

Output:

```
In [6]: IntContainer(3) + 6
Out[6]: 9

In [7]: 6 + IntContainer(3)
Out[7]: 9
```

For more information search for "radd" in the following docs:

- http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names

You'll find other such methods for "right addition", "right subtraction", etc.

Here's another link covering the same operators:

- http://www.siafoo.net/article/57#reversed-binary-operations

By the way, Python does have casting operators:

- http://www.siafoo.net/article/57#casts

But, they won't accomplish what you need in your example (basically because methods don't have any type annotation for parameters, so there's no good way to cast implicitly).  So you can do this:

```
class IntContainer2(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def __int__(self):
        return self.x


ic = IntContainer2(3)
print int(ic) + 6
print 6 + int(ic)
```

But this will fail:

```
print ic + 6  # error: no implicit coercion
```

Answer (score 5):

You won't get conversion operators like in C++ because Python does not have this kind of strong static type system. The only automatic conversion operators are those which handle default numeric values (int/float); they are predefined in the language and cannot be changed.

Type "conversion" is usually done by constructors/factories. You can then overload standard methods like `__add__` to make it work more like other classes.

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you need?

```
In [1]: class IntContainer(object):
   ...:     def __init__(self, val):
   ...:         self.val = val
   ...:     def __add__(self, val):
   ...:         return self.val + val
   ...:     def __radd__(self, val):
   ...:         return self.val + val
   ...:
   ...:

In [2]: i = IntContainer(3)

In [3]: i + 5
Out[3]: 8

In [4]:
```

Comment: Not really.  I was looking for something like the C++ conversion operator, that intelligently replaces the container object with whatever it's containing in expressions.

Comment: This will fail for "5 + i", I believe.

Comment: ars, you are right, I saw your answer and I am missing __radd__ ... I guess now it's ok after I changed my answer...

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for coming to the party 8.5 years late.
You can derive from an immutable (ie. int).  You cannot define `__init__` because the immutable is already created and can't be modified (by definition).  This is where `__new__` comes in handy.

```
class IntContainer(int):
   def __new__ (cls, val):
      ival = int.__new__(cls, val)
      ival._rval = 'IntContainer(%d)' % ival
      return ival
   def __repr__ (self):
      return self._rval

In [1]: i = IntContainer(3)

In [2]: i
Out[2]: IntContainer(3)

In [3]: repr(i)
Out[3]: 'IntContainer(3)'

In [4]: str(i)
Out[4]: '3'

In [5]: i + 5
Out[5]: 8

In [6]: 4 + i
Out[6]: 7

In [7]: int(i)
Out[7]: 3

In [8]: float(i)
Out[8]: 3.0
```

Now, to answer your question about conversion operators.  You can also define `__int__`, `__long__`, `__float__`, and obviously, `__str__`.  To convert or cast to an arbitrary object, you will most likely need to modify the other object to get what you want.  You can use the `__new__` method of that other object.  Or if the other object is already created, try using `__call__`.